# How to read excel file and display data in Yii 2?

Tags: php, phpexcel, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have tried to use PHPExcel library to read the excel file and display data from the file. But it was not working for me.

I have also tried using [yii2-phpexcel](https://github.com/AlexGx/yii2-phpexcel) extension also other some ways but nothing worked for me. I hope I would get help from the expert personnel.

I have used PHPExcel in CakePHP to read data from excel but I have no idea how to make code workable in Yii 2. How can I load PHPExcel in Yii2? I am using XLSX. In CakePHP, I can use-

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Excel/reader'); 
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read(WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
$cells = $data->sheets[0]['cells'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's approximate file structure, extension, size? Add more details please. And show what you have tried.

Answer (score 8):

Install [phpoffice/phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) extension with composer :

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

In your view :

```
$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('./test.xlsx');
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
print_r($sheetData);
```

Comment: I figured it out. The result starts at 1 not 0.. `echo ($sheetData[1]["B"]);`

Comment: this repo has been deprecated in favor of https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: I am [unable to read excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906846/6854117)

Answer (score 0):

As per the instruction given by Christian Lescuyer, I installed the composer dependency. but I had to edit a dependency file.

in file vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE.php, line 288
I had to remove "continue;" and add "break;" in its place.