# Unable to load excel file in Yii2

Tags: php, file

I am using [PHP Spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read an excel file

```
$inputFileName = '/usaid/Files/Installation_Report.xlsx';
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();

try
{
    /** Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

    print_r($spreadsheet);
    exit();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    print_r($exception->getMessage() . $exception->getFile());
    exit();
}
```

But I am getting below error

> File "/usaid/Files/Installation_ Report.xlsx" does not exist.F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php

The path is

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files
```

**Update 1**

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742574/6854117) I have tried to change the code

```
 public function actionRun()
{

    $inputFileName = 'usaid/Files/Installation_Report.xlsx';

    /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
    $inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

    try
    {

        /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

        /**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

        /**  Convert Spreadsheet Object to an Array for ease of use  **/
        $schdeules = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
        //$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

        var_dump($schdeules);
        die();
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
        print_r($exception->getMessage() . $exception->getFile());
        exit();
    }


}
```

Now I am getting

[image]

> InvalidArgumentException
> File "usaid/Files/Installation_Report.xlsx" does not exist.

**Note:** Tried even with `$inputFileName = Yii::$app->basePath.'\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx';` but same result

Comment: did you tried to update your composer ?! and did you check to file is exist or not ?!

Comment: @ttrasn yes I have updated the composer and yes the file is physically present in the folder

Comment: @ttrasn the path is `F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files`

Comment: then remove the leading backslash so try `$inputFileName = 'usaid/Files/Installation_Report.xlsx';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly tried this but same result

Comment: Do `$inputFileName = 'F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx'`

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com already tried but same result :(

Comment: Double-check that the file exists in that folder with that name. There is no reason that `is_file('F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx')` returns `false` if the file exists. And all this has nothing to do with Yii, PhpSpreadsheet or whatever; it's just basic file access.

Comment: @Olivier I have triple-checked it the file does exists..

Comment: What does `is_dir('F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files')` return?

Comment: @Olivier it returns `bool(true)`

Comment: What does `glob('F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\*.*')` return?

Comment: it returns me `array(5) { [0]=> string(40) "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Example.xlsx" [1]=> string(52) "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx" [2]=> string(49) "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Meter_Acceptance.xlsx" [3]=> string(56) "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Meter_Handover_Document.xlsx" [4]=> string(36) "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\logo.jpg" }`

Comment: That's strange. What does `filesize('F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx')` return? And did you try with the other files in that directory?

Comment: @Olivier it gives me `int(16974)` and yes I have tried other files as well and same result is encountered

Comment: Then the file is found. Are you really sure that `is_file('F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx')` returns `false`?

Comment: Is F: a local drive or a letter mapped to a network share?

Comment: @Olivier yes it's a local drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
realpath(Yii::$app->basePath).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Files'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Installation_Report.xlsx';
```

- use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '/'.
- the result should be : "F:\xampp\htdocs\usaid\Files\Installation_Report.xlsx"